# Frontpage pagination issue with paginate_links() function

Tags: pagination, frontpage

I'm using following snippet to output pagination:

```
// get the current page     
if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
    $current_page = get_query_var('paged');
} else if ( get_query_var('page') ) {
    $current_page = get_query_var('page');
} else {
    $current_page = 1;
}

// structure of “format” depends on whether we’re using pretty permalinks
$permalink_structure = get_option('permalink_structure');
$format = empty( $permalink_structure ) ? '&page=%#%' : 'page/%#%/';

echo paginate_links(array(
      'base' => get_pagenum_link(1) . '%_%',
      'format' => $format,
      'current' => $current_page,
      'total' => $total,
      'mid_size' => 4,
      'type' => 'list'
));
```

When I set permalink type to `http://wordpress/?p=123` and use static page for frontpage with pagination, I recieve wrong URLs like:

`http://wordpress/&page=2`

instead of:

`http://wordpress/?page=2`

If you navigate to `http://wordpress/?page=2`, links in pagination will be also wrong, because current URL with queries goes as a base, for example:

`http://wordpress/?page=2&page=3`

If I use any other permalink type with rewriting, everything works fine.

I'm looking any solution  for this snippet and frontpage pagination.

Thanks in advance for any help.

**UPDATE:**
My main problem was a mistype at `&page=%#%` but actually i need `&paged=%#%` and i add condition with is_front_page() function to switch `&` to `?` for frontpage query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* that's because the code is doing strictly what you're *telling* it to do, here:

```
$format = empty( $permalink_structure ) ? '&page=%#%' : 'page/%#%/';
```

Note: `'&page=%#%'`.

Try building your permalink structure using [`add_query_arg()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg), which handles proper appending of `&` vs `?`.

Comment: Can you help me here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/57593/12261